# Different Stylesheets for Different Actions

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

Let's say I have a sessions controller and I have two actions: menu and new.

I have a different stylesheets and html files for each of the actions:

```
menu.css.scss
new.css.scss
```

Unfortunately, when I load each webpage it uses both css files. How can I make this stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem here: http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/

All I had to do was remove `//= require_tree .` from my `application.js` and `*= require_tree.`  from my `application.css`

Then I just precompiled them like so in my `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( menu.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( new.css )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way Rails works (it compiles the stylesheets together into one stylesheet.css), the easiest way to make individual styles work with each action is to add an id for your parent div in the html view for each action and then declare that as the parent in the stylesheet.

```
<div id="menu"...>

<div id="new"...>
```

and in menu.css.scss add this

```
#menu {
 .your_class_details_here {

 }
 .next_style_here {

 }

}
```

in `new.css.scss`

```
#new {
 .your_details_here {

 }
 .next_style_here {

 }

}
```

That way those styles aren't shared between other views.